# What is the equivalent of "Alternatives" for MacOS

Tags: macos, command-line, mojave

Linux distributions have a concept/command called [Alternatives](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/alternatives-command). It's a way to create and manage symlinks to utilities/programs where you can call something by several names.

Example: in all your scripts you reference `vi` but now you want to use `vim`.  Instead of changing your scripts, `alternatives` allow you to link `vim` to `vi`.  Now when you run the script, it will call `vim`.

Is there something similar for macOS?

Comment: Reopened based on the helpful comment from @Allan.

Comment: The general answer most likely will be "there is none". If you look specifically for a way to switch Java versions please ask a new question for this.